# SDL access violation

Tags: c, sdl

I have a big program that is causing me access violation when using sdl_rwops. So I decided to create a small program just to test sdl_rwops and it is causing me the same access violation. For what I could see it is being caused because of the fopen_s() part but I could not figure out why.
Maybe you guys can find what I am missing.
Here is the code:

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include < stdio.h >

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  FILE *file;
  SDL_Surface *screen;
  SDL_Surface *one;
  SDL_Rect rect;
  errno_t err;

/* This is the RWops structure we'll be using */

  SDL_RWops *rw;
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  atexit(SDL_Quit);
  screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 16, SDL_DOUBLEBUF);

/* Here we get a file pointer to a bitmap */

  if ( (err = fopen_s(&file,"penguin.bmp", "r")) != 0)
  {
     printf("Couldn't load penguin.bmp\n");
     exit(1);
  }

/* This is where we actually create our RWops structure.  Here we're
 instructing SDL to get it from the file pointer we just opened */

rw = SDL_RWFromFP(file, 0);

/* SDL_LoadBMP_RW is the RWops version of the old standby,
 SDL_LoadBMP.  This will get the image from the RWops you passed
 in; in this case the file you've opened */

one = SDL_LoadBMP_RW(rw, 0); // This line calls fopen.c and causes the crash

/* Clean up after ourselves */
SDL_FreeRW(rw);
fclose(file);

/* Haphazard way of getting stuff to the screen */
rect.x = rect.y = 20;
rect.w = one -> w;
rect.y = one -> h;
SDL_BlitSurface(one, NULL, screen, &rect);

SDL_Flip(screen);

SDL_Delay(3000);
}
```

And here is the portion of fopen.c that causes the crash of the program:

```
errno_t __cdecl _tfopen_s (
FILE ** pfile,
const _TSCHAR *file,
const _TSCHAR *mode)
{

_VALIDATE_RETURN_ERRCODE((pfile != NULL), EINVAL);

*pfile = _tfsopen(file, mode, _SH_SECURE); // This line causes the access violation

if(*pfile != NULL)
   return 0;

return errno;
}
```

The line

```
one = SDL_LoadBMP_RW(rw, 0);
```

jumps to fopen.c and the line

```
*pfile = _tfsopen(file, mode, _SH_SECURE);
```

in that file makes it crash.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and the picture is in the same folder as the executable. The SDL.dll and even SDL_image.dll are there too.
I found a post in google of the same issue and the person said that when he put the whole path (instead of just penguin.bmp") it would not crash. It did not work for me, crashed anyway.
I am starting to think that it may be some SDL initialization issue but I did anything I could find on google and nothing worked. I tryed running in Multi-threaded DLL (/Md), in Multi-threaded Debug Dll (/MDd), tryed running in 64 bits, tyred changing the Subsystem to Windows and to console... everything resulted in the same crash.

Comment: what is the memory location of the violation?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x77888C39 (ntdll.dll) in testrwops.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014.

Comment: that's a null pointer you have here

Comment: yes, it is pretty clear that it is a null pointer. The question is, why? The file is in the directory, there is check after loading it and it does not fail. I can't get why this pointer is being null. I even checked if (file == NULL) and it is not.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the documentation of SDL_RWFromFP

> Description
>
> SDL_RWFromFP creates a new SDL_RWops structure from a file pointer, opened with stdio. If autoclose is nonzero, the file will be automatically closed when the RWops structure is closed.
>
> Note: This is not available under Win32, since files opened in an application on that platform cannot be used by a dynamically linked library.
>
> Note: This function is not present in SDL-1.2-svn4446

So you need to use SDL_RWFromFile if you want to use RWOps.

Also SDL 2 has many improvements over SDL 1.* and I would highly recommend switching to that.